# IMG on IOS is not loading correcly

Tags: html, css, ios

I can't find why the images are not loading correctly.

PC and Android (Chrome and Firefox):
[image]

Ipad and iphone (safari and chrome):
[image]

.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................

This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>F.S. Website</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="auxiliar/img/brainLogo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/resume/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="logo" href="index.html">Filipe Silva <span>Website</span></a>

      <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="auxiliar/img/menu.svg" alt="Open navigation">

      <nav>
        <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="auxiliar/img/exit.svg" alt="Close navigation">

        <ul class="primaryNav">
          <li class="menus"><a href="#" id="home-id">...</a></li>
          <li class="menus"><a href="#" id="resume-id">...</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="secondary_nav">
          <li class="contact" id="contact-id"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="apresentation" style="padding-bottom: 2em">
    <div class="auxTitle">
      <h1 id="title"></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="fotografia">
      <img src="auxiliar\img\meSuit.jpg" alt="My photo">
    </div>

    <div id="text"></div>
    <div id="download-id">
      <a href="auxiliar\img\CV.zip" download>Download Documents</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <h1>...</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="education" style="padding-bottom: 2em">
    <img src="auxiliar\img\ebsa.png" alt="High school photo" id="imagem_secundaria-id">

    <p>...</p>
    
    <img src="auxiliar\img\isec.png" alt="College photo">

    <p>
...
</p>
  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <h1>...</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="work" style="padding-bottom: 2em">

    <div style="padding: 1em"></div>

    <div class="imagens">
      <img src="auxiliar/img/waiter.png" alt="waiter photo">
    </div>

    <p>
      ...
    </p>

    <div class="imagens">
      <img src="auxiliar/img/reception.png" alt="Recepcionist photo">
    </div>

    <p>
      ...
    </p>

    <div class="imagens">
      <img src="auxiliar/img/suit.png" alt="Recepcionist photo">
    </div>

    <p>
      ....
    </p>
    <div class="imagens">
      <img src="auxiliar/img/foto_empresa.jpg" alt="Internship photo" id="intership_photo_id">
    </div>
    <p>
    ...    
    </p>
  </div>

  <script src="JS/navbar.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/resume_text.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.css:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
.apresentation {
  background-image: url(../../auxiliar/img/pc.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin-top: -6em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
  height: 100vh;
}

.apresentation .auxTitle {
  padding-top: 10em;
}

.apresentation .auxTitle #title {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3d5595;
  font-size: xxx-large;
}

.apresentation .fotografia img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 6em;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 40vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.apresentation #text {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 70%;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.apresentation #download-id {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.apresentation #download-id a {
  color: brown;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: var(--primary-color);
  border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 5px;
}

.apresentation #download-id a:hover {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
}

.title {
  background-color: #3d5595;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-left: -1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
  height: 15vh;
}

.title h1 {
  color: blanchedalmond;
  margin: 0;
}

.education {
  background-image: url(../../auxiliar/img/school.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-left: -1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.education img {
  padding-top: 6em;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: -webkit-max-content;
  max-width: -moz-max-content;
  max-width: max-content;
  max-height: 20vh;
}

.education p {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3em;
  width: 45%;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.education a:link {
  color: #311f62;
}

.education a:visited {
  color: #5c0080;
}

.education a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.education a:active {
  color: blue;
}

.work {
  background-image: url(../../auxiliar/img/work_meeting.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-left: -1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
  display: block;
}

.work .imagens {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.work .imagens img {
  height: auto;
  width: 6%;
  max-width: -webkit-max-content;
  max-width: -moz-max-content;
  max-width: max-content;
  max-height: 20vh;
}

.work p {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 45%;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.work #intership_photo_id {
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: -webkit-max-content;
  max-width: -moz-max-content;
  max-width: max-content;
  max-height: 20vh;
}

.work a:link {
  color: #311f62;
}

.work a:visited {
  color: #5c0080;
}

.work a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.work a:active {
  color: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 2500px) {
  .apresentation {
    height: auto;
  }
  .apresentation .auxTitle {
    padding-top: 8em;
  }
  .apresentation .fotografia img {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .education {
    height: auto;
  }
  .education img {
    padding-top: 6em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: -webkit-max-content;
    max-width: -moz-max-content;
    max-width: max-content;
    max-height: 20vh;
  }
  .work {
    height: auto;
  }
  .work .imagens {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 1em;
  }
  .work .imagens img {
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: -webkit-max-content;
    max-width: -moz-max-content;
    max-width: max-content;
    max-height: 20vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 1500px) {
  .apresentation {
    height: auto;
  }
  .apresentation .auxTitle {
    padding-top: 8em;
  }
  .apresentation .fotografia img {
    padding-top: 6em;
    height: 50%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: -moz-max-content;
    min-width: auto;
  }
  .education {
    height: auto;
  }
  .education img {
    padding-top: 6em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: -webkit-max-content;
    max-width: -moz-max-content;
    max-width: max-content;
    max-height: 20vh;
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  .work {
    height: auto;
  }
  .work .imagens {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 1em;
  }
  .work .imagens img {
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: -webkit-max-content;
    max-width: -moz-max-content;
    max-width: max-content;
    min-height: 10vw;
    max-height: 20vh;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: I've seen this question before. It's because of the background-attachment fixed which IOS doesn't deal with well. Put the background onto a pseudo element fixed position instead.

Comment: @AHaworth Can you give an example please? I'm not understanding how to do it

Comment: Read up about pseudo element before. Put one on each of your elements (e.g. apresentation) making it position absolute, z-index: -1, position: fixed and with width and height 100% and positioned top and left 0.